# Singularity 3.11.0 installation failing when running ./mconfig

Tags: go, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-20.04, singularity-container

I am trying to install Singularity version 3.11.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, following the instructions provided in this [link](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/latest/user-guide/quick_start.html#quick-installation-steps). However, when I run the ./mconfig command, the installation fails with below error:

```
bool876@bool876:~/singularity-ce-3.11.0$ go version
go version go1.20.1 linux/amd64
bool876@bool876:~/singularity-ce-3.11.0$ ./mconfig && \
>     make -C builddir && \
>     sudo make -C builddir install
rm: cannot remove '/home/bool876/singularity-ce-3.11.0/builddir/config.h': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/bool876/singularity-ce-3.11.0/builddir/config.c': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/bool876/singularity-ce-3.11.0/builddir/makeit-intermediate/base.mk': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/bool876/singularity-ce-3.11.0/builddir/makeit-intermediate/testprogs': Permission denied
```

Can someone please help me identify the cause of this error and suggest a solution to successfully install Singularity?

Answer (score -1):

Your `builddir` might have the wrong permissions. Try deleting it `sudo rm -r builddir` and then rerunning the install command.